# How to reference outlet inside custom cell from a different class (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, custom-cell

I have a tableView with a custom cell that has a `UITextView` inside it and I want to make the `UITextView` of the last cell in the tableView the firstresponder when a button is pressed. However, I'm not sure how to reference that `UITextView` inside the cell.

It has an outlet in the custom cell class, but I don't know how to use this button (an action in another class) to reference it.

```
class ActionCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var label: UITextView!
}
```

What I tried is this, but it doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func addAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: -1, section: 1)) as? ActionCell
    let textview = cell?.contentView.subviews.filter{$0 is UITextView}
    textview![0].becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: I dont test here, but you try cell.label.becomeFirstResponder() ?

Comment: Thanks @ClaudioCastro, I tried that and it sounds like it should work, but it doesn't, the textview just doesn't become active.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce here.

Comment: Actually, I'm an idiot. I was referencing section: 1 when I was meant to reference section: 0. It works perfectly, thank you. If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'll accept it right away.

Comment: Good thing it solved

Comment: The -1 doesn't seem to work as a way to select the last cell. Do you know if that's the correct way to do it?

Comment: I was not sure about your -1 so I was going to test it. Do you want the last cell of a certain section, correct? You can use tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: X) - 1  (you have ti use -1 because begin in 0

Comment: The complete line for section 0 : let cell = tableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) -1, section: 0))

Comment: It only seems to work for the first one, but I think it's something else I'm doing wrong, because even if I do dataArray.count, so take it straight from the horse's mouth, it behaves the same. Could I show you the rest of the code please? This should work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195025/discussion-between-claudio-castro-and-cristianmoisei).